# How to make a player have to destroy squares in a specific order?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I create a simple 2D Unity ( C#) animation, which is a tutorial for me.

I have a PLAYER.

1) My player moves with the mouse (he follows mouse).

2) After colliding with a square, he destroys it.

I don't have a problem with it, everything works ok.

**However, I would like the player to destroy the squares in the right order(in right sequence): 1-2-3-4.**

**If he destroys them in the wrong order(wrong sequence) , for example 1-3 (first collid with number 1 and then number 3), animation end.**

I know how to end animations when I touch an wrong thing, but I do not know how to make it in the right order (specific sequence).

**How to make a player have to destroy squares in a specific order?**

PS. Sorry for my English. If someone doesn't understand something, I'll try to write it simpler :)

Until now, with the help of tutorials, I did something like that:

```
 // this script is on the empty game object; just one of these, and it keeps track of which game object is the right one to be destroyed next.
int index = 0;

[SerializeField]
GameObject [] gamePieces;



public void GotDestroyed(GameObject go) {
   if(gamePieces[index] == go) {
      // correct one was destroyed.
      ++index; // if index >= gamePieces.Length, it's game over.. all done.


  }
    else {
       // if we're here, the one destroyed was not the next in the list
    }
 }
```

But how to further transform this code to solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots and lots of different ways to achieve this. There is no best solution, just the solution which fits best into the software architecture of your game.

One solution you could use is to add a variable `public Square previous` to your Square behaviour. Use the Inspector to assign to each square the previous square in order. Leave it `null` for the first square.

In your code which handles the square collisions, check if `previous == null`. Destroyed objects are considered equal to null by Unity, so this condition will return true if the previous square was destroyed or never assigned in the first place.

Another approach would be to have a `Square[] squares` in your Player behaviour and an `int nextSquare` which says which entry in the array is the one which needs to be visited next. When the player collides with a square, check if `squares[nextSquare] == collidedSquare`.